# What are the autogenerated lextab.py and yacctab.py files when running a GAE app?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I had done some GAE development in the past and not run into any `lextab.py` or `yacctab.py` files. But I downloaded latest SDK and now every time I run an application, it takes a while to startup and there are two files generated - `lextab.py` and `yacctab.py`. what are these files? Are they a side-effect of GAE or have something to do with my python environment?

Comment: GAE does not generate those files; are you using [Python Lex-Yacc](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html)?

Comment: I am not using it. I installed python from pythonxy.org. Then I just installed GAE SDK. How can I get rid of this thing please?

Comment: pythonxy includes Python Lex-Yacc (according to their [docs](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/wiki/Downloads): "ply upgraded to standard plagin status. It is a dependency of Enthought's enaml.") so perhaps you are calling it indirectly or perhaps pythonxy is calling it for you. Any reason you can't run standard [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-279/)?

Comment: I see. How can I get rid of this junk? I am on windows and don't have pip.